# Mysql close connection after some hours

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm running a whatsapp bot in nodejs that connects to mysql and every message performs actions in the database.

With each trigger of this the database connection object is created, the problem is that every day after a few hours of use the node generates this error:

```
Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 21 but received 0
node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: The client was disconnected by the server because of inactivity. See wait_timeout and interactive_timeout for configuring this behavior.
    at Connection.protocolError (C:\Users\Woton\Desktop\zeplin_bot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:421:17)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Woton\Desktop\zeplin_bot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:476:14)
    at PacketParser.onPacket (C:\Users\Woton\Desktop\zeplin_bot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:94:12)
    at PacketParser.executeStart (C:\Users\Woton\Desktop\zeplin_bot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Woton\Desktop\zeplin_bot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:101:25)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection.protocolError (C:\Users\Woton\Desktop\zeplin_bot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:424:10)
    at Connection.handlePacket (C:\Users\Woton\Desktop\zeplin_bot\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:476:14)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  fatal: true,
  code: 4031
```

The connection is made as follows:

```
this.conn = mysql.createConnection({
                database: 'database',
                host: "host",
                user: "user",
                password: 'pass'
            });
```

At the end of each call I close the connection like this

```
this.conn.end()
```

I thought about increasing the times of `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout`, but from what I understood that would only make the problem take longer to occur, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to use connection pool instead of managing connections by yourself. It’s common for DB to have limit on how long connection could be open, so even if nothing goes wrong eventually connection will be closed.

You could read [here](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/836#issuecomment-414281593) that the error could be resolved by starting using connection pool. And [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) you could find more information on ways to use connection pools in node.js